# Creating an SQLAlchemy engine based on psycopg3

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, psycopg3

I need to upgrade the following code to some equivalent code based on `psycopg` version 3:

```
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://', creator=connector)
```

This psycopg2 URL worked like a charm, but:

```
import psycopg # v3.1
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg://', creator=connector)
```

(I also tried the 'psycopg3' word without success)

returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_1032556/253047102.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg://', creator=connector)

  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 309, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 534, in create_engine
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 661, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 343, in load
    raise exc.NoSuchModuleError(

NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgresql.psycopg
```

So, how to properly create an SQLAlchemy engine based on `psycopg` (v3.x)?

My `sqlalchemy` version is: '1.4.35' (tried version `1.4.40` but face an `AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy' has no attribute 'dialects'` error).

psycopg3 doc: https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/
sqlalchemy doc: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html

Comment: it isn't supported yet, and will only be availble in the yet to be released sqlalchemy 2.0. 
 see https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/6842

Comment: This is possible as of SQLAlchemy 2.0.x which just recently released. If you migrate to 2.0 you should be able to use Psycopg3. See release notes here: 
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/whatsnew_20.html#dialect-support-for-psycopg-3-a-k-a-psycopg

Answer (score 21):

Just an update to the current answer: Sqlalchemy 2.0 has been released and it does support psycopg3. You need to upgrade to 2.0 to use it.

Note the connection string will have to be changed from `postgresql` to `postgresql+psycopg` or SqlAlchemy will (at time of writing) try using `psycopg2`.

See docs here for more info: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg

Comment: assuming sqla 2 and psycopg3 - how is it meant to be used ?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg

Answer (score 5):

SQLAlchemy does not support psycopg3 in the 1.4.x series. The part after the + symbol is a package inside the sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.{engine} where engine is psycopg2, asyncpg or something other.

Other dialects work the same way.

But there is no psycopg nor psycopg3 driver in the 1.4.x series.